# real time update plist populate UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, detailtextlabel

Im trying to create an application that will show in a table 3 floors and in the detailTextLabel show how many computers are available in those floors. For now I dont have the realtime data but I want to just keep some fake fixed data for now and be able to plug in the real data later.

I thought I would create an array, FloorList and FloorListAvailable. Floor list would contain "First Floor" "Second Floor" "Third Floor" and FloorListAvailable would show a number of how many computers are available.

Im currently unsure on how to go about this, it sounds easy enough to do but I cant wrap my head around it. I thought about using NSDictionary. I have used the .plist but can that be changed to by dynamic when I get the real time data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

1. generate the realtime data by a script (e.g.); JSON would be a good format
2. let your app download the data files with a suitable frequency
3. parse the JSON (see: [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) into own objects; e.g. arrays
4. use these arrays as the data sources for your table views
5. whenever you get new data, send `reloadData` to your table views